# How to find the values of m & n in $2^{m} - 2^{n} = 56 ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, exponentiation, factoring

I've tried this in two ways :

**First Way :**

$2^{m}- 2^{n} = 56$

$2^{m}(1-2^{n-m})= 2^{3} × 7$

Comparing the exponents, we get
$m = 3$

And,

$1-2^{n-m} = 7$

$n = 6$

**Second Way :**

$2^{m}- 2^{n} = 56$

$2^{n}(1-2^{m-n})= 2^{3} × 7$

Comparing the exponents, we get
$n = 3$

And,

$1-2^{m-n} = 7$

$m = 6$

Is what I've done correct ? If this method is correct, why I'm getting different answers, just by factorising it in two different ways ?

Comment: If $1 - 2^{n - m} = 7$ with $m = 3$, $n \ne 6$. $1 - 2^{6 - 3} = -7$.

Comment: You should be able to see that some of your expressions are negative...

Comment: If you factor by $2^n$, you should get $2^n(2^{m-n}-1)= 56$, not what you wrote.

Comment: As for how to find this... depending on if you allow it or not, you can write $56$ in binary as $111000_2$ and figure this out that way as being $1000000_2-1000_2$

Comment: The second way contains a sign error. But the idea is valid.

Comment: Ok ! I've now realised that in the second way I have broke the non-commutativity law of subtraction ! But what's wrong with the first one ?

Comment: It is because the factor $1-2^{n-m}$ is not an integer so you can no longer compare with the product of integers that you have on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can only be a solution because $2^m-2^n=56>0\Rightarrow2^m-2^n>0$, so $m>n$, and therefore you can only do:
\begin{align}
2^n(2^{m-n}-1)=56=2^3\times7
\end{align}
Where do you have to $n=3$ y $m=6$.